# Google Docs embedded viewer IE 9 not display, using ASP classic

Tags: asp-classic, google-docs-api

Using Google Document viewer on a ASP classic website.
The problem I have is that it doesn't display the document in Internet Explorer 9. I haven't seen anyone solve this problem from a developers perspective.

The problem I assume has to do with IE9 security settings, but my IE8 renders it fine.

Is there any way to solve this without getting the user to do something?

It works fine in Firefox and Chrome.

My embeded viewer looks like this:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2F<%=linkToDoc%>&embedded=true" width="663" height="938" style="border: none;">
```

Answer (score 0):

as i had a quick view on google doc viewer. it has no downloadable plugin to patch into your script. there are two ways of using it. use `<%=link from source(db or request function)%>` to get the file and use an iframe

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=(LINKforDOCUMENT)&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

or you could use this plugin 
[Google Docs Viewer - plugin for Jquery](http://www.jawish.org/blog/archives/394-Google-Docs-Viewer-plugin-for-jQuery.html) .

it both seems to work in all browsers.

Comment: Sorry if I didnt make this clear. I can embed the viewer and it works in most browsers, but in IE9.

Comment: can i see your embedding code? i have tryed on ie9 ,firefox , chrome and opera.it seems to be working good.

Comment: Yeah I put it up.

`code`<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2F<%=linkToDoc%>&embedded=true" width="663" height="938" style="border: none;">